# Understanding suppressed exceptions

Tags: java, exception

I've just run into a [logback bug](https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1027) related to loops in the exception chains. In my case, I have

```
throwable.getSuppressed()[0].getCause() == throwable
```

The logback bug doesn't bother me at the moment, my problem is the cycle.
I'm staring on my the stacktrace and I can't understand how it happens.

The stacktrace is very long an involves my own code only. It spans many classes, so I can't post it here without posting too much code.
I check that

- I never use `Throwable::addSuppressed` explicitly (that's sure)
- no involved exception gets thrown in a finally block
- any caught exception is used as the cause

but I might be overlooking something. Could someone tell if its possible to get the above cycle when my assumption is valid?

There's a place where the exception gets stored to be wrapped and rethrown later, could this be the culprit?

Could someone give a simple example producing such a cycle?

Comment: Any try-with-resources blocks?

Comment: @shmosel Not in the code pointed by any stacktrace element.